# How to Initialize an array in Assembly Language

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86-16

Kindly tell me how to initialize an array in Assembly Language e.g
Initialize an array named as “Even”, which contain first ten EVEN numbers.
Even = 0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18

Initialize an array named as “Odd”, which contain first ten ODD numbers.
Odd=1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21

Add Both arrays (index wise) into a third array named as “Sum”.
SUM [0] = Even [0] + Odd [0]

SUM [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LG0oa.jpg) = Even [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LG0oa.jpg) + Odd [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LG0oa.jpg)

Up to

SUM [n] = Even [n] + Odd [n]

[image]

Comment: Your classmate asked this earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43692896/3857942

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking to solve homework

Comment: its not a homework, Just a given task to know the idea that how we can do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways of doing this. The simplest to create the array in a declaration:

```
EVEN:
 .WORD 0, 2, 4
ODD:
 .WORD 1, 3, 5
```

Using whatever size data you want.

To add them, you can:

1. Unroll the loop
2. Us a macro
3. Call a recursive function

Comment: Ahan thats good 

Comment: How can i unroll the loop??? Can u please brief me??

Comment: Just do the addition 10 times inline.

Comment: Ok Got it and ,kindly tell me about this, we have the following register values:

 
AX
FA10
DS
32FA
SI
222A
BX
050C
CS
6FDE
SP
6D6E
CX
1202
ES
E9A2
BP
FF21
DX
FFEF
SS
CD33
DI
2829
 

You are required to calculate the physical address generated by each of the following instructions.

MOV [bP+Fa21], AX
ADD CX, [SP+FaFa]

Comment: Depends on the system and the setup of the page tables.

Comment: What will be the physical address of MOV [bP+Fa21], AX if we have AX= FA10, BP= FF21